# Closure declaration in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

In swift 2.0, what is the correct closure declaration? I've seen examples done like below, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

In `SomeClass`:

`var successBlock: (Bool) -> () = { _ in }`

and it would be called like this:

`self.successBlock(true)`

Then in `SomeOtherClass`:

```
let someClass = SomeClass
someClass.successBlock {
    success in
    //code here

}
```

Bit this gives me an error: `(_) -> is not convertible to Bool`

I've tried googling around a bit but with no luck...
Is there a syntax change with swift 2.0 or is it me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to *set* the `successBlock`, you should do it with an `=` sign:

```
someClass.successBlock = { success in
    // code here
}
```

EDIT: You mentioned that you only want your other class to "listen", but what does "listen" mean? If you want to listen to every time the closure gets called with some value and do something depending on it, you may want to have an array of closures instead:

```
var successBlocks : [Bool -> Void] = []
```

which you can invoke like this:

```
let value = true
successBlocks.forEach{ $0(value) }
```

When you want to listen to invocations, you can do this:

```
someClass.successBlocks.append( { success in
    // do the stuff
} )
```

which won't override any other closures already in the array, so probably that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: My `SomeClass` is the one setting the block. `SomeOtherClass` is listening for it

Comment: @Chris If you want another class to do something with the value each time the `successBlock` is invoked, you should set the block as in my answer to do the thing your other class wants to do.. You can either set the closure, or execute it, there's nothing in between

Comment: Ok, so that works... Would you mind explaining why that works? my `SomeOtherClass` should only listen, not set it, so why is the `=` sign needed? Sorry if I'm being thick

Comment: @Chris Edited my answer :)

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to explain it! Much appreciated